# How can I know if my post(comment, answer, question) was Flagged?

Tags: support, badges, flags, posts

Is it possible to see if my post was flagged. The only way as I see it, if you see your post has got deleted, them may be someone might have flagged it for moderation. But is there other way to see if your post was flagged for moderation.

I am wondering if someone's is repeatedly flagged for posts, maybe he can be assigned a badge(bad one :) )

But right now, I want to know if it is possible to see how many posts of mine were flagged.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. We can't know which post is/was flagged by others. Flags are private: only moderators can see flags on posts, and see which posts belonging to a given user have been flagged.

Once upon a time, it was possible to see how many flags were active on a given post. This tended to make authors upset, and would also prompt pile-on flagging. So this is no longer possible.

Comment: The only exception is duplicate flag, which leaves an auto comment. :)